# Ubuntu 16.04 Connects to Ethernet and Wifi but no Internet

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet

As the title says, I cannot connect my new Ubuntu computer to the internet by any means. I am not sure if I am dealing with three independent problems here, or if is something more fundamental is preventing me from accessing the internet. Any help appreciated.

### Ethernet

Ubuntu connects (slowly) to a router when connected directly with a cable. There are other computers on the network so I know its not the router. The router does not even register the new computer, and I don't get an IPv4 address, and there is no data transfer. I've tried disabling IPv6 and that does nothing.

### Wifi

As before there are other computers on the wifi network. I've tried the (ralink RT2760) Wifi Card in another Ubuntu computer and that works fine, so its not that. Ubuntu sometimes connects to the wifi after a few minutes but there is no data transfer, and sometimes it doesn't connect at all. I have tried disabling IPv6 and that makes no difference. I have even tried booting the disk from the new computer on an old computer with the new wifi card, and the wifi works, so I know my drivers are OK.

### Bonus: Tethering through my Mobile

I can also connect my other Ubuntu computers by tethering them through my android phone. Doesn't work on the new computer since it either crashes my phone, or sometimes I get the error message

```
Unable to open MTP device '[usb:002,010]'
```

when I activate the tether.

### Terminal Outputs

```
route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         *               0.0.0.0         U     1002   0        0 enp3s0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 enp3s0

lspci
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
04:07.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT2760 Wireless 802.11n 1T/2R

rfkill list wlan
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

ifdown wlp4s7
Unknown interface wlp4s7

ifconfig (when connected to wifi)
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:8d:5c:8f:94:ec  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1644 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1644 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:120528 (120.5 KB)  TX bytes:120528 (120.5 KB)

wlp4s7    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1f:1f:3c:26:8a  
          inet addr:192.168.0.9  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2a02:810d:12c0:d4b:c893:9437:3913:6aad/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a02:810d:12c0:d4b:21f:1fff:fe3c:268a/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::21f:1fff:fe3c:268a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:84 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2763 (2.7 KB)  TX bytes:13791 (13.7 KB)

dmesg (extract)
[  868.636154] wlp4s7: send auth to 54:67:51:01:c7:d7 (try 1/3)
[  869.904104] wlp4s7: send auth to 54:67:51:01:c7:d7 (try 2/3)
[  870.904066] wlp4s7: send auth to 54:67:51:01:c7:d7 (try 3/3)
[  871.892046] wlp4s7: authentication with 54:67:51:01:c7:d7 timed out
[  872.075996] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 0 failed to flush
[  877.091384] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s7: link is not ready
[  877.251889] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 0 failed to flush
[  877.411906] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 0 failed to flush
[  878.464502] wlp4s7: authenticate with 54:67:51:01:c7:d7
[  878.631789] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 0 failed to flush
[  878.639934] wlp4s7: send auth to 54:67:51:01:c7:d7 (try 1/3)
[  879.879839] wlp4s7: send auth to 54:67:51:01:c7:d7 (try 2/3)
[  879.935703] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s7: link is not ready
[  879.938278] wlp4s7: aborting authentication with 54:67:51:01:c7:d7 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

Comment: I have seen the 'flush queue' error previously and I'm working on a theory. Would you please change your router to use  B and G speeds only, rather than auto B, G and N and reboot the router? See if the flush queue error is resolved and you connect.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done so already, I would try trying a new ethernet cable or use a cable that you know works with other computers. Slow partial connection may mean a faulty cable.